# Mysql: Sorting with Not In

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT deals.* FROM `deals` as deals 
JOIN cities_deals as cd on cd.deal_id=deals.id and cd.city_id='1'
```

Which will select all deals and then group them by the city they are in. I now want to get a list of all deals that are not in cities_deals at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM deals
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT deal_id FROM cities_deals)
```

An alternative way to write it is to use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM deals AS d
LEFT JOIN cities_deals AS cd
ON cd.deal_id = d.id
WHERE cd.deal_id IS NULL
```